# If else statement in Jmeter Beanshell post-processor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I get response from my request containing request id and if something goes wrong there is a err code.

I want to write a beanshell script that would look firstly if there is any err code, if not it would wirte request id into the csv file. I am not able to find anything about if else statements in beanshell

```
if (there is an err code){
write it to the csv file}
else {write request id to csv}
```

is it possible in beanshell or better to use assertions ?

Problem with java

```
2016/08/09 13:38:38 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService; import java.io.PrintWrite . . . '' : Command not found: regexMethod( java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) 
2016/08/09 13:38:38 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService; import java.io.PrintWrite . . . '' : Command not found: regexMethod( java.lang.String, java.lang.String )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the job... You just need to get regex expressions for your data.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String prevResponse = JMeterContextService.getContext().getPreviousResult().
                          getResponseDataAsString();

public void writeToFile(String toWrite) {
    String path = "/home/username/Desktop/TSO_test_failure.csv";
    File file = new File(path);
    try {
           PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
        writer.print(toWrite); 
        writer.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String regexMethod (String regex, String text) {
    String regResult;
    try {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher mac = pat.matcher(text);
        mac.find();
        regResult = mac.group(1);
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return regResult;
}

String result = null;
if (prevResponse.contains("errorCode")) {
    String errRegex = "findErrorID"; // change this to meet your needs!
    result = regexMethod(errRegex, prevResponse);
} else {
    String reqRegex = "findRequestID"; // change this to meet your needs!
    result = regexMethod(reqRegex, prevResponse); 
}
writeToFile(result);
```

Comment: great man ! One more question. What value should (errorCode) get. I mean, should I set it in previous steps ?

Comment: So basically, it will check if response contains some text with error, and from there do what you want depending on the result.

Comment: Ok, get the point. I set everything and it should work now, however, I still receive errors. Look to my first post.